# SSH connection attempt hanging after "loaded 3 keys"

Tags: ssh, version

I am attempting to establish a simple, password-controlled SSH connection but have encountered a hanging problem. The client terminal output is something like the following:

```
[d3pd@ppepc145 ~]$ ssh user@10.194.248.43 -v
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.194.248.43 [10.194.248.43] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file REDACTED/d3pd/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file REDACTED/d3pd/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file REDACTED/d3pd/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
```

At this point, the client simple hangs.

The corresponding server `/var/log/auth.log` log entry is as follows:

```
Jun 12 12:49:20 m93p sshd[7232]: Did not receive identification string from 194.36.1.172
```

I have verified that `sshd` is running:

```
d3pd@m93p:~$ ps ax | grep sshd
 7152 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
 7301 pts/13   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto sshd
```

I have verified that the SSH server appears to be listening to the appropriate port (22) using `netstat -taupen`:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          227957      7152/sshd
```

What should I try in order to attempt to establish a simple, password-controlled SSH connection?

The reported OpenSSH version of the server is `OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014` and the reported OpenSSH version of the client is `OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008`.

Comment: You can add up to three v's to the `ssh` command line to get more logging detail: `ssh -vvv user@host...`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. At the second debug level, the only additional printout is ``debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0``, which is presented just before the printout mentioning the I.P. address of the server.